# Jqgrid Vurtual/True Scrolling becomes slower as more rows get loaded in

Tags: performance, jqgrid, virtual, scroll

This is a question similar to this:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/vurtualtrue-scrolling-becomes-slower-on-row-selection-as-more-rows-get-loaded-in

I need to have an answer about this issue, why does the jqgrid does not unload pages when scrolling down? Is there a workaround about this?

It only unloads pages when scrolling up.

This has as an effect that the performance drops more and more as more pages are loaded when scrolling down.

Thank you.